# C++ Objected building function returning Base class type

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have been away from c++ for a long time and so am rusty, but should I be able to do this? I want to build the object and then cast it into the more specialized derived class.

```
#pragma once

class GameObject
{
public:

    GameObject();
    virtual ~GameObject();

    int x, y;

}

class PlayerObject : Public GameObject
{

    PlayerObject();
    virtual ~PlayerObject();

    int x, y;
    string name;

};


class Game
{

    unique_ptr<GameObject> randomObject;
    unique_ptr<PlayerObject> player;


}

#########################



unique_ptr<GameObject> GameObjectManager::buildGameObject(string gameObjectId)
{

    unique_ptr<GameObject> gameObject;
    gameObject = make_unique< GameObject>();

    return gameObject;

}


##################################
int main(int argc, char *args[])

{


    unique_ptr<GameObject> rock = gameObjectManager.buildGameObject("ROCK"));
    unique_ptr<PlayerObject> playerObject = dynamic_cast<unique_ptr<PlayerObject>>(Game::gameObjectManager.buildGameObject("PLAYER"));



}
```

Is it say to do a dynamic cast liek this. What would be the better way to go for a situation like this? Thanks

Comment: My advice would be to not do this. Instead look into virtual functions and cast as a nearly-last resort.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty standard, see: [covariant return type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type).